# NSString thinks it is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have run in to issue like that 
My `NSString` has a weird behaviour 
after this:

```
NSMutableArray *_keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[_currentContact.phoneNumbers allKeys]mutableCopy]];
NSString *fail = [_keys objectAtIndex:0];
```

my `NSString *fail` (in debugger) says it is `null` but when I do print it, it has the proper string.

I think it has something similar to [this](http://blog.jackhl.com/2012/05/03/how-to-debug-objective-c-unrecognized-selector/).

But how to fix that? How can I fix the issue so my fail string won't be `null` and will hold the right string in it ?

Edit:

Right after

```
  [_selectedphoneType setText:[_currentContact.phoneNumbers objectForKey:fail]];
```

I have crash for unrecognised selector I think it is because the fail is `null`.

Comment: The link you posted is about *Unrecogised Selector* exceptions and seems unrelated to your issue ?!?

Comment: @Droppy I have unrecognized selector later in code because of the string is null

Comment: if you do an if statement like if (fail != nil) immediately after you set the fail NSString, do you enter it?

Comment: @Will Yes I do enter in it

Comment: @user3351949 then can you post the code where you are getting the string is nil crash because it appears that it is not. Are you changing what fail is equal to later?

Comment: @Will No I do Not :(

Comment: @Rob But when i try to access the dictionary using the `fail` string which is key I crashing

Comment: @Rob I posted down below

Comment: Oh, I thought you said you examined `fail` and it was not `nil`. Show us your evidence to your claim that "it has the proper string".

Comment: @Rob `Printing description of fail:
mobile` Which is the right key

Comment: @user3351949 your currentContact.phoneNumbers dictionary (I think its a dictionary, you haven't told us what it is) must have lost the value of what key use to be pointing to. If you put NSString *mobile = [_currentContact.phoneNumbers objectForKey:fail]; on the line above where you are setting the selectedphoneType you can see if you are failing there or at the setting.

Comment: @Will The dictionary is set , and I don't change it afterwards (Yes it is a dictionary) _selectedPhoneType is an UILabel

Comment: @Will I have done what you said `nsstring * mobile = my dict object for key fail` and it work -> can I have some explanations ?

Comment: @Will but when i did [selectedphoneType setText:mobile ]; I have an exception -> -[PhoneNumber copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc0ae040

Comment: It would appear to be an instance of a `PhoneNumber` class, not a string. By the way, your title to this question, that you think it is null, is obviously not the case.

Comment: @Rob Yeah I see now.., Thank you :)
But still can't get why my string was Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the key is really a string in your case. I doubt that.

would have added as a comment.. but have lesser reputation, so please ignore.

Comment: But I need it to be an NSString anyway !

Comment: @user3351949 Fine, you may need to extract some string value from this object. You must identify what property/method of this object's class (a `PhoneNumber`, apparently) will retrieve a string representation.